# Generating serial no based on two criterias

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

I have Prod_ID which is unique and description which will be same for different prod_ID. I need to generate serial no like Group 1, Group 2 based on both criteria . Serial no should be unique for one prod_ID & description. Is there any formula or macro to do this asap, because i have 50,000 + rows.

```html
Serial ID Description
Group 1 30-0661 Medium
Group 1 30-0661 Medium
Group 1 30-0661 Medium
Group 1 30-0661 Medium
Group 2 30-0661 Narrow
Group 2 30-0661 Narrow
Group 2 30-0661 Narrow
Group 3 30-0661 Wide
Group 3 30-0661 Wide
Group 3 30-0661 Wide
Group 3 30-0661 Wide
Group 3 30-0661 Wide
Group 4 30-0661 Extra Wide
Group 4 30-0661 Extra Wide
Group 4 30-0661 Extra Wide
Group 4 30-0661 Extra Wide
Group 4 30-0661 Extra Wide
Group 5 30-0662 Medium
Group 5 30-0662 Medium
Group 5 30-0662 Medium
Group 5 30-0662 Medium
Group 5 30-0662 Medium
Group 5 30-0662 Medium
Group 5 30-0662 Medium
Group 5 30-0662 Medium
Group 6 30-0662 Narrow
Group 6 30-0662 Narrow
Group 6 30-0662 Narrow
Group 6 30-0662 Narrow
Group 6 30-0662 Narrow
Group 6 30-0662 Narrow
Group 6 30-0662 Narrow
Group 6 30-0662 Narrow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight your ID and description columns and go to the data tab on the ribbon and select **Advanced** in the Sort & Filter section.

Choose *Copy to another location*, tick the *Unique records only* box, select somewhere to the right of your data as the *Copy to* location and press *OK*.

This will give you a set of all the combinations which can then be numbered sequentially.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon K :)